# Find mean of one variable, depending on another, which is grouped by a third

Tags: r, grouping, mean

R amateur here. I have a dataset where I'd like to find the mean value (hours) for each observed behaviour, for day and night periods. Sample below.

| Period | Behaviour | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Day | Walking | 3.5 |
| Day | Standing | 2 |
| Night | Grazing | 5 |
| Night | Lying | 4.5 |

Ideally I'd like to get the mean values (hours) for each behaviour for day and night. I tried using;

> aggregate(df$Hours, list(df$Behaviour), mean)

This gives me mean values for each behaviour as a whole, I don't know how to further group by Period to get day and night split. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Period, Behaviour) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(Hours, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Period [2]
  Period Behaviour   avg
  <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
1 Day    Standing    2  
2 Day    Walking     3.5
3 Night  Grazing     5  
4 Night  Lying       4.5
```

Or maybe this is base R:

```
aggregate(df$Hours, by = list(df$Period, df$Behaviour), FUN = mean)

  Group.1  Group.2   x
1   Night  Grazing 5.0
2   Night    Lying 4.5
3     Day Standing 2.0
4     Day  Walking 3.5
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: My pleasure. The only problem with your code was you should have included the second grouping variable `df$Period` in to the list of `by` argument of `aggregate` function. In fact you got it totally right.

Comment: I was close. Very new to R but enjoying it so far! Thanks again for the speedy reply. Much appreciated.

Comment: Just read the documentations fully this is where you can learn all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Or we could use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(avg = mean(Hours, na.rm = TRUE)), .(Period, Behaviour)]
```